# Scroll freezes on iPad (javascript)

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ipad, scroll

I develop app for iPad on javascript. I have some div. Content in this div should be scrollable. I added scroll for div using this class:

```
.scrollable {
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

This way works in 90% cases, but sometimes I try scroll content and nothing happened. I wait about 3 sec and try it again  - and scroll works. I don't have any workaround javascript code which  may lead to such behavior.

Why this behavior can be?

Comment: Which version of iOS? I've encountered similar behavior on iOS5.

Comment: We need more code, like the HTML. A http://jsfiddle.net would be great.

Comment: you loading that content dynamically or thats static. Try giving `height` attribute to your `.scrollable` div.

Comment: This behavior is reproduced on iOS 7.0 anв iOS 7.1. This is jsfiddle  link http://jsfiddle.net/AnnaMiroshnichenko/373JH/  , this is jsfiddle  full screen result link http://jsfiddle.net/AnnaMiroshnichenko/373JH/embedded/result/  . I added content dynamically and set height.

Comment: I founded interesting features. One finger scrolling and two finger scrolling generated different events. https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/handlingevents/handlingevents.html  How can I imitate  two finger scrolling (on javascript-side) if user will scroll page using one finger?

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that you were loading content dynamically but your fiddle doesn't have that dynamic content load taking place, so I can't answer with a fork of your fiddle, as I would prefer.

However, I just recently had a very similar problem and found that if, **after** the content is loaded (timing is critical), I set any of the scrollable elements to use `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`, it seems to resolve the odd "freezing" behavior.

(In my instance, my dynamic content was loaded in with jQuery's `$.get` shorthand, so I used the `.then()` to run a function which would automatically set the appropriate CSS **every time** new content was loaded.)

Let me know if this helps.